# Paypal error: "rp_lookup_failed", "Unable to read RP metadata"

Tags: api, token

I am developing an AngularJS app, and i was trying to test PayPal transactions. I create and APP and get ClientID and Secret, and then I wanna get an access token. I try with this

```
storeApp.controller('payPalController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http)
{
    $scope.paypal = function()
    {
              $http({
                  method: 'POST',
                  url: 'https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token',
                  headers: {
                  'Accept': 'application/json',
                  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                  'Authorization': 'Basic AeHZj_qxaxXkqKQWIjt4vLN1kL7dfpmn-aTiE3u0eLVGZBQut1DXA8qgMq8N22GCjTLrZUOSg4BC6hvH:EAsK3JWlOW1rPNRelHWuy3qmNWMwg74t2K_CizaBQGaT10OyMyEY7pVVBJJC2RZCZXthaNL7iBfGULzN',
                  },
                  data: 'grant_type=client_credentials'
              })
              .success(function()
              {
                  console.log("It works!");
                  //console.log(data);
              })
              .error(function()
              {
                  console.log("It fails!");
                  //console.log(data)
              });
    }
}]);
```

But when I execute it form browser i get this:

> {"error":"rp_lookup_failed","error_description":"Unable to read RP
>   metadata: Request failed with exception :
>   com.paypal.foundation.exception.DataAccessRuntimeException\nErrors:\n\tPIMP_RC_INTERNAL_ERROR
>   Client  exception, while calling UserRead.read_identity_partner_app
>   2.0:\n"}

On the other hand, at the same time, I get this warning.

> This site uses a SHA -1 certificate; It is recommended to use
>   certified signature algorithms that use stronger than SHA- 1 hash
>   functions.

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, the reason is - you need to Base64 Encode the Authorization header. (client_id and secret).

So, replace this line:

```
'Authorization': 'Basic AeHZj_qxaxXkqKQWIjt4vLN1kL7dfpmn-aTiE3u0eLVGZBQut1DXA8qgMq8N22GCjTLrZUOSg4BC6hvH:EAsK3JWlOW1rPNRelHWuy3qmNWMwg74t2K_CizaBQGaT10OyMyEY7pVVBJJC2RZCZXthaNL7iBfGULzN'
```

by this line:

```
'Authorization': 'Basic QVVBZ3dEdzNrUUEwa0NBblFRZWdVR1M4R19zb3pBdkV5NFY1RUppdm5JTVdSQVJESnNQR2VGWHZBWEo1NjlfOGhGelgzdkxWS21jU0JyTnQ6RUVkbUdHNFptaGRCSlJwQjZMek9VLWJWQmU3NEZIWm8xam9TTGM0V0tiTzg2cS15TWk1ZTA5NUxXUHlhVHIxa2YxWjBDdHB3YU40WGxmMmw='
```